# Can Mann-Whitney U be used for Likert-Type Item?

Tags: categorical-data, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have recently run a Man-Whitney U for ordinal data (a 4 point Likert Scale) and gender. Now, I have made sure that the variance was equally distributed as the assumption requires. I turned Likert data to ranks and ran a Levines test. A supplemental statistic book states that DV for M-W U needs to be continuous.

Comment: There's not actually an assumption of equal variance for the Mann-Whitney (though interpretation may be easier if there is; it really depends on what hypothesis you're interested in, since a more restricted pair of hypotheses may need it).  The usual derivation of the distribution of the test statistic under the null relies on continuous distributions but you can use the statistic without that as long as you appropriately deal with the effect of discreteness on the null distribution (in large samples where a normal approximation is used this boils down to a simple adjustment to the variance)

Comment: See some of the posts under related in the sidebar $\to$

Comment: In asking this kind of question, it is often important to clarify if the data being analyzed are single Likert items or a Likert *scale* composed of several Likert items.